# C++ : Confused on something about functions

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myFunc (unsigned short int x );

int main ()
{
    unsigned short int x, y;
    x=7;
    y = myFunc(x);
    std::cout << "x:" << x << "y: " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int myFunc (unsigned short int x )
{
    return (4 * x );
}
```

Now this ^ Code works, but when I change

```
y = myFunc(x);
```

into

```
y = myFunc(int);
```

it will no longer work, why is that?

Comment: Why would it work? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the compiler expects **the value** of type `unsigned short int`, but you've passed **a type** `int`. What did you expected to get? The result of `4*int` is undefined.

You can pass types when you use templates. Take a look on the following sample:

```
// Here's a templated version of myFunc function 
template<typename T>
T myFunc ( unsigned short int x )
{
    return (4 * x );
}

...

y = myFunc<int>( x ); // here you can pass a type as an argument of the template,
// but at the same moment you need to pass a value as an argument of the function
```

Answer (score 5):

```
y =myFunc(int);
```

This is not a valid expression. `int` is a type, you cannot pass a type as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 3):

if
x=7;

y = myFunc(x); **is equal to** y = myFunc(7);

if you use int, what value it has? so the error occurs

Comment: computer executes as like you solve your algebra equations.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because int is a reserved word. And even if it wasn't - you haven't declared (and defined) identifier called "int".